# Two ways to define methods in react,what's the different?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am learning React, I find out there's two different ways to define methods in a Component Class.

one way is to define a method as a class method:

```
handleCategorySelected(category){
    this.setState({
        category
    })
};
```

but first need to bind method to **this** in constructor method.

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.handleCategorySelected = this.handleCategorySelected.bind(this);
}
```

After bind，I can use it in JSX.

```
render() {
    return <Fragment>
        <Footer
            onSelect={this.handleCategorySelected}
        />
    </Fragment>
}
```

Otherwise it will throw an Type error:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'setState' of undefined
```

The second way is more simple,

```
handleCategorySelected = (category) => {
    this.setState({
        category
    })
};
```

and after this definition,I can use this method in JSX without bind 'this' in the constructor method;

what's the different between two ways,and why is the first way throws an error without bind 'this',and why is the other way does not?  what's the different?

Comment: The arrow function ensures `this` inside the callback function is inherited from the surrounding scope, rather than it being something else from the handler with `onSelect={this.handleCategorySelected}`

Comment: you can read this article https://medium.com/quick-code/react-quick-tip-use-class-properties-and-arrow-functions-to-avoid-binding-this-to-methods-29628aca2e25

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Method 1 is called [public class fields syntax](https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-plugin-proposal-class-properties), using it and we don't need to worry about the meaning of `this` in runtime because it's automatically bound. For example:

```
class LoggingButton extends React.Component {
  // This syntax ensures `this` is bound within handleCategorySelected.
  // Warning: this is *experimental* syntax.
  handleCategorySelected = () => {
    console.log('this is:', this);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <button onClick={this.handleCategorySelected}>
        Click me
      </button>
    );
  }
}
```

---

In Method 2, it's just a normal method on the class, a common pattern is for an event handler when you define a component using an [ES6 class](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes)

However, when using this method, you have to be careful about the meaning of `this` in JSX callbacks. In JavaScript, class methods are not [bound](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Function/bind) by default. If you forget to bind `this.handleClick` and pass it to `onClick`, `this` will be **undefined** when the function is actually called.

```
class LoggingButton extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    // This binding is necessary to make `this` work in the callback
    this.handleCategorySelected = this.handleCategorySelected.bind(this);
  }
  handleCategorySelected() {
    console.log('this is:', this);
  }

  render() {
    return <button onClick={this.handleCategorySelected}>Click me</button>;
  }
}
```

---

The difference between method 1 and method 2 is about the meaning of `this` inside the function when the function is actually called.

---

Reference: [Handling Events](https://reactjs.org/docs/handling-events.html)

Comment: Tnx for the explanation!